# Categories missing in Eclipse preferences

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

It turns out that I am trying to follow a guide x, and it turns out that one of the screenshots shows me the following:

[image]

But when I go to the preferences of my Eclipse it doesn't appear... Does anyone know why it could be?

[image]

My version of eclipse is the following:

[image]

Comment: You probably need to download the version for enterprise developers.

Comment: What version was the guide using? And why do you have a Tomcat category?